# Appending data from dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am attempting to generate a JSON output from a dataframe and I'm not sure why the values are not being assigned separately:

```
emails = []

if len(df) > 0:

    for index, name in df.iterrows():
        try:
            value = str(df.names)
        except:
            continue

        email = { 
        "names": value
        }
        emails.append(email)

print(json.dumps(emails, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "names": "0       abby\n1    josh\n2    john\n3       heather\n4       justin\nName: value, dtype: object"
    }, 
    {
```

Desired output"

```
[
    {
        "names": abby
 }, 
    {
        "names": josh
 }, 
    {
        "names": john
}

]
```

Comment: You want only names form your dataframe? or entire dataframe to be converted into Json?

Comment: I just want the names from my dataframe and I'm not sure how to get it to loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.to_json()`

```
names = df[["names"]]
print(names.to_json(orient="records"))
```

Refer [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! 

emails = []

if len(email_list) > 0:

    for index, student in email_list.iterrows():
        try:
            students = int(ids,student_ids)
        except:
            continue

        email = { 
        "StudentEmails": [student.email], 
        "student": students,
        }
        emails.append(email)
        
print(json.dumps(emails, indent=4))

Can you please also tell me how I would be able to add names as a line to this JSON output from the separate dataframe when I attempted it separated the names.

Comment: @Abby_Hameed it's bad idea to loop over pandas dataframe, you can directly use `pandas functions` to generate output you want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
value = str(df.names)
```

Use

```
value = list(df.names)
```

Series object are not serializable by default but list are serializable. For example this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2,4,5]})
json.dumps(list(df.a))
```

will output:

```
'[1, 2, 4, 5]'
```

Answer (score 0):

emails = []

if len(email_list) > 0:

```
for index, student in email_list.iterrows():
    try:
        students = int(ids,student_ids)
    except:
        continue

    email = { 
    "StudentEmails": [student.email], 
    "student": students,
    }
    emails.append(email)
```

print(json.dumps(emails, indent=4))

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the actual data(`name.names`) not the whole column(`df.names`)

try:

```py
if len(df) > 0:

    for index, name in df.iterrows():
        try:
            value = name.names
        except:
            continue

        email = {
        "names": value
        }
        emails.append(email)

print(json.dumps(emails, indent=4))
```